# MSDTC ERROR After separating application and database to different servers

Tags: c#, sql, rpc, msdtc

I have a dot net application which initially was hosted in the same box with its database,after separating the two to different boxes i keep on getting errors with MSDTC

This is the error log

communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed. at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[] propagationToken) at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction tx) at System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx) at System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Promote(InternalTransaction tx) at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote() at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction transaction) at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction transaction, Byte[] whereabouts) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction transaction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction transaction) at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe() at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode() at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression) at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

**MSDTC Setting on both machines**
[image]

I have also opened port 135 and port 5000 to 50020 in both firewalls.

What might be the issue someone assist me plsease.

Comment: Have you tried taking a step back i.e. can your application still perform a basic connection to the Database and perform a simple read to return some records?

Answer (score 0):

```
    This solved my issue
```

I edited below file in both servsers,added their IPS and assigned names to the machines I was able to ping the two machines from each other using the assigned names,then changed the confing file datasource to the names instead of using ips

This is the exact line that i edited
xxx.16.100.1     JpAppServer              # x client host

```
    C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc

    # Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
    #
    # This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
    #
    # This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
    # entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
    # be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
    # The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
    # space.
    #
    # Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
    # lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
    #
    # For example:
    #
    #      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
           xxx.16.100.1     JpAppServer              # x client host

    # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    #   127.0.0.1       localhost
    #   ::1             localhost
```